# Is there a closed form for this sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over 4n+1}\left({1\over 2^{4n+1}}+{1\over{3^{4n+1}}}\right)?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am very curious to what is the closed form for

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1\over 4n-1}\left({1\over 2^{4n-1}}+{1\over{3^{4n+1}}}\right)?\tag1$$

I can't recall any formulas relate to $(1)$ at the moment.

Comment: there is a 'nice' formula

Comment: and where should i do this?

Comment: You can just ask Wolfram Alpha to evaluate it for you - http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_(n%3D0)%5EInfty+1%2F((4n%2B1)*2%5E(4n%2B1)) - but of course, that won't tell you how it _got_ that...

Comment: $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x^{4n}=1/(1-x^4)$ ...integration is elementary...set $a=1/2$ and $a=1/3$..add...be happy

Comment: $$S=\frac{1}{8} (\pi +2 \log 6)$$

Comment: I really think there should be some searchable text in the title. Also, 123 stop flagging this post. There is nothing strange going on here. And, we will not delete this question.

Comment: @123 The question likely has -3 because there is no demonstration of effort from you to solve this problem. Good questions not only ask a math question, but also discuss the approaches that the OP attempted. This way, the other users on math.se can help with specific difficulties the OP is having. Otherwise, it looks as if the OP may be trying to get others to do their work for them.

Comment: @123: changing the $4n+1$ term into a $4n-1$ term has the side-effect of making the answers below almost useless, hence wasting the efforts of the answerers. *Chamaleon questions* should be completely avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to apply a [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) to
$$ \forall x\in(-1,1),\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{n} = -\log(1-x)\tag{A}$$
or
$$ \forall x\in(-1,1),\qquad \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \text{arctanh}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\tag{B}$$
leading to:
$$ \forall x\in(-1,1),\qquad \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{4n+1}}{4n+1}=x\cdot{}_2 F_1\left(\tfrac{1}{4},1;\tfrac{5}{4};x^4\right)=\frac{\arctan x+\text{arctanh } x}{2}\tag{C}$$
and through $\arctan\frac{1}{2}+\arctan\frac{1}{3}=\frac{\pi}{4}$,
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4n+1}\left(\frac{1}{2^{4n+1}}+\frac{1}{3^{4n+1}}\right)=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{1}{4}\log(6).}\tag{D}$$

---

About the second version of the question,
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{4n-1}}{4n-1}=\frac{x^3}{3}\cdot{}_2 F_1\left(\tfrac{3}{4},1;\tfrac{7}{4};x^4\right)=\frac{\text{arctanh}(x)-\arctan(x)}{2} \tag{Cbis}$$
allows us to state:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4n-1}\left(\frac{1}{2^{4n+1}}+\frac{1}{3^{4n+1}}\right)=\color{blue}{\frac{\log 2}{36}+\frac{\log 3}{16}-\frac{5}{6}-\frac{\arctan(1/2)}{8}-\frac{\arctan(1/3)}{18}}\tag{Dbis}$$

Comment: It looks like the question was edited since we posted our answers. I also got down voted for suggesting this procedure, possibly because of the change. It's frustrating to have the sands shift beneath your feet. That's how it goes, I guess.

Comment: @Joel: I understand your frustration, chamaleon questions should be banished, but I guess it is pretty difficult to detect them, on a software basis.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** let $a\in\left[0,1\right]$. Can you calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4n+1}a^{4n+1}$ using integration with respect to $a$?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4n+1} x^{4n+1}$, then $f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{4n}.$

Now you can use the geometric series formula to represent $f'(x)$ and work backwards from that.